# How to list all values greater than a specific value from an array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

What i have done so far is Sort out the Top 3 position of values of an array, but i am looking out to get the only values which are more than 0.20..... in Descending order.

```
label = np.array(genres)
print(label)
#OUTPUT:  [0.1892372  0.29031774 0.19473006 0.01859367 0.10489976 0.20222157]
label = label.argsort()[::-1][:3]
```

Output i am getting is :

```
Output:
[1 5 2]
```

Output looking for :

```
label = [0.29031774 0.20222157]
[1 5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get those specific indices and then index -

```
# Get all valid indices
In [12]: idx = np.flatnonzero(label>0.2)

# Index into input array and get descending order
In [20]: idx[np.argsort(label[idx])[::-1]]
Out[20]: array([1, 5])
```

Variations of `np.flatnonzero()`, would be `np.nonzero()[0]` and `np.where()[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

pls attach this

```
labelargs = label.argsort()[::-1][:3]
print(labelargs) ## this will print [1 5 2]
labelargs = [x for x in labelargs if label[x]>0.2]
print(labelargs) ## this will print [1 5]
```

regards